# How can I add data to BigQuery without problems with rate limits?

Tags: python, pandas, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I currently have a system in which I want to send data from that system via a Google Cloud Function to BigQuery (using Python). My idea was to do this in two simple steps:

1. The system calls a Google Cloud Function and sends JSON data to that function
2. The Google Cloud Function unpacks the data and stores it inside a Google BigQuery table using the pandas-gbq package.

I thought it was a good idea, until I realized there were rate limits on Google BigQuery regarding adding data (see https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/Known-Limitations-of-Adding-Data-into-Google-BigQuery?language=en_US for example).

Because I want to use this system to trigger more than a thousand times a day, I think I need a better setup.

What would you recommend me to do?

I already thought of two things:

1. Using Google Datastore for adding data, but I am not sure whether that has the same kind of rate limits and if I can easily transfer that data to BigQuery
2. Instead of sending data on a case-by-case basis, collect (for example) 500 calls to a Google Cloud Function. Once the data of 500 cases is received, send those 500 cases in one go to BigQuery. I am not sure whether this will work and if it's even possible to do this with Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: To stream data to BigQuery you should probably consider a different architecture. Use Pub Sub -> Data Flow -> BigQuery. Example can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/tutorials/dataflow-stream-to-bigquery

Comment: Thank you so much! And the way to go forward is to send the data with the Google Cloud Function to  Pub Sub > Data Flow > BigQuery, right?

Comment: You can sent data directly to Pub Sub, via API. Usually it is enough. Any processing can be done with DataFlow.

Comment: Hi jorenwouters, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mentioned limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) only apply to *load jobs*.

You can use [*streaming inserts*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows) instead, which do not have those [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts).

I am not sure if *pandas-gbq* uses load jobs or streaming inserts under the hood.
Anyway, you can also use the [BigQuery Python Client](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html) and the method [insert_rows_from_dataframe](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows_from_dataframe) which uses the streaming API.

Comment: So with this solution, I should call a Google Cloud Function from my system. Then, that Google Cloud Function gets the data from the system and inserts it in BigQuery using the Streaming API?

Comment: That would be one way to do it. I simply answered the question in your title, how to avoid BQ rate limits; that is with the streaming API. From your text I assumed that you are using a cloud function is given. How you trigger that cloud function is up to you and depends on your use case. There are various options including Cloud Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can use Google provided Dataflow Templates that contain templates where you can use Pub/Sub to stream data into BigQuery using Dataflow. A streaming pipeline is used to read the JSON formatted data from Cloud Pub/Sub and then write it to BigQuery.

You can choose either [Pub/Sub Topic to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtobigquery) template or [Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubsubscriptiontobigquery) template according to the requirement. It will incur some cost in BigQuery for data ingestion, for which you can check the pricing given in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).

Comment: And to get the data from the system into Pub/Sub, you can use the Pub/Sub API? (So I do not need to use a Google Cloud Function to get the data in Pub/SUB)

Comment: Hi @jorenwouters, yes, you need not to use Cloud Functions and can directly get the data from system into Pub/Sub.